# Where should I put background and button image files? Assets or just drag into the app files?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app but I'm not quite sure where should I put the image files? Just drag and copy inside the app or in assests? What's the difference, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Put them in the same folder as your code. Another option is when you have a project open, drag and drop the file into your project, and click "copy if needed" and it'll put it in your project for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using the `xcassets`, which you can do by dragging your files onto it when you have it open in Xcode. Xcode handles the rest, copying them into your project. Doing this also allows you do call `UIImage(imageNamed:)`, using the title you give to each Image Set. You also don't have to worry about specific naming of the different size classes, as you drag them to the appropriate section there.